# How to decompress a file

Tags: python

My code has a file "filefile.txt" which has a compressed sentence in it. The file is laid out like :

```
1
2
3 
4
5
1
2
6
9
10
11
2
12
12
9

This 
is
a 
sentence
.
too   
!
Yo
yo
bling
```

The original text that I want to decompress says "!"

My code says:

```
fo = open("filefile.txt","r")
script = fo.readline()
script2 = fo.readline()
fo.close()
script2 = script2.split()
script = [s.strip("\n") for s in script]

sentencewords = []

while len(script) > 0:
    for p in script:
        sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.index(p)))
        script.remove(0)

print(sentencewords)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Computing code attempts\AT13.py", line 46, in <module>
    sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.index(p)))
ValueError: '1' is not in list
```

I need `sentencewords` to contain "This is a sentence. This is too! Yo yo bling bling!"

I have changed it now but it still doesn't work.
        sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.enumerate(p)))

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "F:\Computing code attempts\AT13.py", line 46, in 
    sentencewords.append(enumerate(script2.enumerate(p)))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'enumerate''

Does anyone know if there is another way round this problem or how to fix my current code?

```
fo = open("filefile.txt","r")
script = fo.readline()
script2 = fo.readline()
fo.close()
script2 = script2.split()
script = [s.strip("\n") for s in script]

sentencewords = []

indexes = []
for line in fo:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
        indexes.append(line)
    else:
        break


words = [line.strip() for line in fo if line.strip()]

while len(script) > 0:
    for p in script:
        sentencewords.append(words[index-1])


print(sentencewords)
```

Updated code but I don't know what the I/O thing means in the latest output from python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Computing code attempts/attempt14.py", line 45, in <module>
    for line in fo:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix my code, I'd be grateful for

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Please  give your question a title that indicates the contents of the question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/312450

Comment: `enumerate(script2.index(p))` is causing the error since script2 is a single line of the file and you are trying to get the character at p which is equal to '1', since script is the first line of the file. 1 does not exist in script2, hence the error '1' is not in list. As far a "tweaking" your code, I would throw this away and think about what steps you need to do to compete this task, write some pseudo code, and then try to write it python.

Comment: That's great, but I've tried pseudo code, I've tried thinking about my steps but I just can't get my head around the problem, this was a last resort as I've been trying for weeks. This website was meant to help people, I thought because no one I know in real life can help me I thought I'd ask people here. Throwing away my code is like throwing away weeks of effort. Even if to some people it would probably only take minutes to write. As you can see I'm not very clever.

Comment: Writing code that doesn't work doesn't mean that you aren't clever.  You just haven't known Python for as long as some of us have.  There are thousands of people who have made much stupider mistakes.

Comment: You don't need to use `.index()` here, but you should use indexing.  You should do something like `indexes = []` `for line in fo:` `if line.strip().isdigit():` `indexes.append(line)` `else:` `break`.  That creates a list of the indexes.  You can then create a list of the words with `words = [line.strip() for line in fo if line.strip()]`  After that, you can iterate through `indexes` and for each index, append `words[index-1]` to `sentencewords`.

Comment: thanks, I have changed it but still doesn't work, going to update question...

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses a file parsing while the file is close:

```
fo.close()
...
indexes = []
for line in fo:
```

You can delay the `fo.close()` to the end of your script and it will pass the `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`